# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to insert into the table the columns "file_number" and "file_id". file_number should be self-increasing as it is the PRIMARY KEY.I think the problem is on the the cur.execute(_insert, [file_id]) line. _insert being the SQL statement and the item between square brackets is the string to be inserted. I think it´s throwing the error as I´m not including "file_number" in those square brackets. But how should I include something that is to be incremented by itself? I still don´t get that. Thanks in advance!

```
class Image:
    _name = "image"
    table = f"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "{_name}"
    (   "file_number" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        "file_id" TEXT
    );
    """

    def __init__(self, db: SQL):
        self.db = db

    def add(self, file_id):
        """Agrega una file_id a la base de datos"""
        _insert = f"""INSERT or IGNORE INTO {self._name}(file_number, file_id)
        VALUES(?,?)"""
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        cur.execute(_insert, [file_id])
        self.db.commit()
        cur.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for the Autoincrement value](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used.

In other words, you don't need to specify the autoincrement value at all, it will be given an unused integer on an insert, then the number of bindings and the number of parameters you're passing in will match up:

```
_insert = f"""INSERT or IGNORE INTO {self._name}(file_id)
        VALUES(?)"""
// ...
cur.execute(_insert, [file_id])
```